# GTA online motorcycle businesses

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

In GTA Online, I own 3 motorcycle club businesses (them being the meth lab, cocaine warehouse, and the document forgery office) and I buy supplies for each of them.
However, if I decide to disband my motorcycle club and become a CEO, will my 
motorcycle club businesses keep producing stock for me to eventually sell?

I have tried going into a CEO business before, and my stock stayed the same. Is this supposed to happen to my motorcycle club business?

Also, will my bunker and hangar still produce stock when I am in a motorcycle club business?

Answer (score 3):

Your businesses will continue to produce stock so long as you are playing the game in Online mode and and have supplies.  It doesn't matter whether you're an MC president or a CEO, or neither; also, you can be playing a mission. The stock will continue to accrue - but the supplies run down pretty quickly, so you won't accrue much.

The stock production will be faster if the upgrades are applied. I recommend buying the Nightclub, as you can assign nightclub staff to produce stock from your MC businesses as well.  Nightclub staff are able to produce regardless of supply status. In fact, I don't bother stocking supplies and rely 100% on nightclub staff doing the heavy lifting for me.

Comment: Actually, it keeps producing even while you are not playing Online

Comment: Not if it's working properly ;)

Comment: At least on the PS4 it does. I'll log off one night, and have 300k worth of product when I log on the next morning.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely not correct... enjoy it while you can. I know people who purposely stayed logged in (e.g. rubber band on wired controller) and they can restock product that way, but not while offline.

Comment: It might be cause I keep my system in rest mode